# ExtJS: How to scale down a form that overfloat out of the screen

Tags: extjs

I have a simple Feedback Form like [this](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/24ue). When I run, it seems that the form is two big out of the screen so I can not see the form completely. How can I scale it down to fit the screen?

Thank you!

Comment: Will this screen have a fixed size, or will it be a responsive screen?

Comment: I am not sure yet, but rightnow I just want to test it on the screen of my laptop